# Custom Material UI library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

"I created a UI library using Material UI and encapsulated MUI components in a way that they remain consistent across all projects. I then created a React library. When I install this library in different projects, I set up a theme in the main project and wrap the entire project with ThemeProvider. Later, I used components from my library within the pages. In some cases, the palette colors of my configured theme work, while in some cases, they don't. What could be the reason for this, and is there anyone who can help?

Here's the button component I wrote in the library:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { QButtonTypes } from './QButton.types';
import { Button, styled } from '@mui/material';
import { buttonDefaultSX } from '../../../theme/defaultsx';

const AButtonStyled = styled(Button, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop,
})(({ theme, ...prop }) => {
    return {
        '& .MuiButtonBase-root': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette[prop.color],
        },
    };
});

const AButton = ({ children, ...props }: QButtonTypes) => {
    return (
        <AButtonStyled
            disableElevation
            {...props}
            sx={{ ...buttonDefaultSX, ...props.sx }}
        >
            {children}
        </AButtonStyled>
    );
};

export default AButton;
```

Here's how I use it in the project:

```js
<Stack
    spacing={4}
    component="form"
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleOtpSubmit)}
>
    <AButton type="submit" variant="contained">
        Login
    </AButton>
</Stack>
```

In Next.js 14, here's how I use ThemeProvider:

```js
import React from 'react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import theme from '.';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function ThemeRegistry(props) {
    const { options, children } = props;

    const [{ cache, flush }] = React.useState(() => {
        const cache = createCache(options);
        cache.compat = true;
        const prevInsert = cache.insert;
        let inserted = [];
        cache.insert = (...args) => {
            const serialized = args[1];
            if (cache.inserted[serialized.name] === undefined) {
                inserted.push(serialized.name);
            }
            return prevInsert(...args);
        };
        const flush = () => {
            const prevInserted = inserted;
            inserted = [];
            return prevInserted;
        };
        return { cache, flush };
    });

    useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
        const names = flush();
        if (names.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        let styles = '';
        for (const name of names) {
            styles += cache.inserted[name];
        }
        return (
            <style
                key={cache.key}
                data-emotion={`${cache.key} ${names.join(' ')}`}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: styles,
                }}
            />
        );
    });

    return (
        <CacheProvider value={cache}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                {children}
            </ThemeProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
    );
}
```

Any help on why the theme colors sometimes work and sometimes don't would be appreciated!"